# In which HTML tags can I put javascript callbacks?

Tags: javascript, html, callback

I am trying to place a callback in an element like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">
Click
</button>
```

However, I would not like to use `button`.
Is there anything else I could use instead?

I tried placing the callback in a `<p>` and an `<a>` element. I did not work however.

Comment: Why dont you use event listeners on the p tag?

Comment: Very strange question. Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve? You can set `onclick` attribute of any tag - so it's up to you what exactly tag to use. And what exactly "did not work however",, what gave you tried? For example, this code definitely works: `<p onclick="alert('clicked');"> Some text</p>`

Comment: Onclick works in any element that you write in. But is not good practice. Write separately javascript and html.

Comment: I am using JSX and I am trying to make a callback. However, if I use `<p>`, I get: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type object`

Answer (score 2):

Adding the eventlistener via JS would be a more agnostic way.

First give your p tag an id eg:

```
<p id="pTag"></p>
```

then for example:

```
<script>
    var pTag = document.getElementById('pTag');
    pTag.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
</script>
```

Comment: you should select an element not a collection of elements

Answer (score 1):

You can place onclick handlers in pretty much any HTML tag, except these:

```
<base>
<bdo>
<br>
<head>
<html>
<iframe>
<meta>
<param>
<script>
<style>
<title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have mistyped your function name, or have an object elsewhere that has the same name.